# can we make price negotiable chatbot on dialogflow?

Tags: mysql, e-commerce, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I want to make an E-commerce web application in which customer can negotiate on price with chatbot. All product related data is stored in mysql database.
is it possible to make price negotiable chatbot on dialogflow.
Requirements:

1. Chatbot should return responses user queries and get data from
   mysql. example:if i ask the price of specific product so chatbot
   should tell me correct price.
2. Chatbot should be able to negotiate and persuades customers to buy
   the product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dialogflow is great at handling *what the user is saying*, but leaves the rest to you.

(1) is only partially handled by Dialogflow - it will tell you what the user is trying to do, what they're inquiring about, what price they're offering, etc. But it is up to you to implement a fulfillment webhook that queries the database based on what the user has said.

Similarly, to handle (2) you will need to setup a fulfillment webhook which is responsible for doing the negotiation and persuasion.

Comment: thanks for your response one thing that i want to ask you is that, is there any other way to make such kind of chatbots means implementing NLP algorithms.

Comment: There are other NLP/NLU libraries and tools out there, yes.

Answer (score 2):

1. Sure, just create a "AskPrice" intent in dialogflow which you will link with your backend. It will fetch the price from DB and return it to the user.
2. This will be a bit tricky, but it will depend on the business logic (how much can a bot negotiate, on what occasion...). You can have a negotiation flow which is triggered when the user asks for a price.